# Sorting in postgresql with different criteria to each column in case of tie

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have a problem with sorting in postgresql. The information must be sorted in descending order according to the first column, but in case of a tie, the information must be sorted in ascending order according to the second column.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 36):

`SELECT ... ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC`

Answer (score 17):

```
select *
from t
order by c1 desc, c2 asc
```

Comment: I've tried this one before but it does not work as it should. The sorting order is allways the creteria of the first column. I don't know why.

Comment: @user22 Yes the first. If there is a tie then the second. I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 13):

Of course.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY

> The ORDER BY clause causes the result rows to be sorted according to the specified expression(s). *If two rows are equal according to the leftmost expression, they are compared according to the next expression and so on.*

and later

> Optionally one can add the key word ASC (ascending) or DESC (descending) *after any expression in the ORDER BY clause.*

one more:

> Note that ordering options apply only to the expression they follow; for example ORDER BY x, y DESC does not mean the same thing as ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC.

Emphasis, my own.